# What is Haskell used for in the real world?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, programming-languages

There is a lot of hype around Haskell, however, it is hard to get information on how it is used in the real world applications. What are the most popular projects / usages of Haskell and why it excels at solving these problems?

Comment: No, I won't because it's a clear cut answer. No wiggle room for opinions and such. I just want to know what the language was created for.

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775726/whats-the-fuss-about-haskell

Comment: @Papuccino1, wait, do you want to know what it's _useful_ for, or what it was _created_ for? The former is what the question is asking, and there's a lot of room for opinion there...

Comment: @Papuccino1 - What benefit do the extra words in your title bring to the question? Also, I think you're misunderstanding the use of the term "functional" in this context, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Agree on the dupe, though the titles of both questions make them look Subjective & Argumentative.  I'm not sure it's a good idea to edit the title of a 6-month-old question though.

Comment: According to their own website many companies use it for different kinds of purposes... 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_industry

Comment: Because it's turing complete, anything! Just because it's functional doesn't mean it can't do things!

Comment: [This document](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md) gives a good overview of the strong and weak points of the Haskell ecosystem.

Comment: I've discovered one "quality of life" advantage of strong type system. You can search for functions by their type. That means I don't have to know what it's called, but I know what it does, and it's enough most of the time.

Comment: @bdonlan You know a slight change of words makes this not opinion based.  Just ask what kind of projects is haskell used in.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

> What are some common uses for this
>   language?

Rapid application development.

If you want to know "why Haskell?", then you need to consider advantages of functional programming languages (taken from https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdvantagesOfFunctionalProgramming):

> - Functional programs tend to be much more terse than their ImperativeLanguage counterparts. Often this leads to enhanced
>     programmer productivity
> - FP encourages quick prototyping. As such, I think it is the best software design paradigm for ExtremeProgrammers... but what do I know?
> - FP is modular in the dimension of functionality, where ObjectOrientedProgramming is modular in the dimension of different
>     components.
> - The ability to have your cake and eat it. Imagine you have a complex OO system processing messages - every component might make state
>     changes depending on the message and then forward the message to some
>     objects it has links to. Wouldn't it be just too cool to be able to
>     easily roll back every change if some object deep in the call
>     hierarchy decided the message is flawed? How about having a history of
>     different states?
> - Many housekeeping tasks made for you: deconstructing data structures (PatternMatching), storing variable bindings (LexicalScope with
>     closures), strong typing (TypeInference), GarbageCollection, storage
>     allocation, whether to use boxed (pointer-to-value) or unboxed (value
>     directly) representation...
> - Safe multithreading! Immutable data structures are not subject to data race conditions, and consequently don't have to be protected by
>     locks. If you are always allocating new objects, rather than
>     destructively manipulating existing ones, the locking can be hidden in
>     the allocation and GarbageCollection system.

Apart from this Haskell has its own advantages such as:

- Clear, intuitive syntax inspired by mathematical notation.
- List comprehensions to create a list based on existing lists.
- Lambda expressions: create functions without giving them explicit names. So it's easier to handle big formulas.
- Haskell is completely [referentially transparent](https://wiki.haskell.org/Referential_transparency). Any code that uses I/O must be marked as such. This way, it encourages you to separate code with side effects (e.g. putting text on the screen) from code without (calculations).
- Lazy evaluation is a really nice feature:

  - Even if something would usually cause an error, it will still work as long as you don't use the result. For example, you could put `1 / 0` as the first item of a list and it will still work if you only used the second item.
  - It is easier to write search programs such as this [sudoku solver](https://web.archive.org/web/20130823222012/http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/comp150fp/archive/richard-bird/sudoku.pdf) because it doesn't load every combination at once—it just generates them as it goes along. You can do this in other languages, but only Haskell does this *by default*.

You can check out following links:

- https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdvantagesOfFunctionalProgramming
- https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/wesdyer/why-functional-programming-is-important-in-a-mixed-environment
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160626145828/http://blog.kickino.org/archives/2007/05/22/T22_34_16/
- https://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2007/05/advantage-of-functional-programming.html

Comment: The following thought often crosses my mind: in a pure language, a function always returns the same result when passed the same parameters. This is a guarantee. Imperative languages in contrast build everything on top of "statements". A statement does not come with any sort of guarantee (except its execution consumes time and produces heat). So the foundation is already shaky and everything bult on top of it will remain shaky. To me this was one of the reasons to learn haskell.

Comment: Haskell is very, very far from what I would traditionally consider to be "RAD" in the likes of Visual Basic or Delphi. RAD is less about the language and more about tools like GUI designers and the associated generation of boilerplate by the tools.

Comment: @BarendVenter, RAD is not so much about how long in minutes it takes the developer to get something on the screen, but more about the ability to "turn on a dime" during prototyping. In a typical imperative codebase, major structural changes, as is frequent in prototyping, require significant amounts of cut&paste (order of statements) and re-writing classes from scratch, even changing interfaces.

Comment: That Microsoft calls VB a form of rapid development is just marketing, IMO. Having a graphical builder gives you the ability to easily add widgets to an application in an intuitive manner, but that's pretty much it. Anything else can be done as easily with just a text editor.

Comment: It's been 6 years since this question was asked and since the Go programming language debuted. Despite having a weaker type system and generally being "objectively inferior" (according to functional/ML fans), it's managed to ship more (and more important) software in those 6 years than Haskell has in its 26 years. I mean this as a case study; there are clearly things that are holding functional languages back, and they can't all be attributed to hype.

Comment: You forgot a point - coding in haskell is an absolute blast ;) I've had so much fun trying my hand at some problems in haskell.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg Of course statements come with guarantees. What sort of useful language would have statements without guarantees? For example in C `x = 5;` guarantees that after it executes, `x` contains the value `5`.

Comment: You probably meant: *For example, you could put 1 / 0 as the **second** item of a list and it will still work if you only used the **first** item.*

Comment: @immibis `x = 5` in _C++_ definitely does not guarantee that `x` contains the value `5` after it executes (operator overloading). @lovasoa Both statements are true, since it is possible to access and evaluate the second item in a list without evaluating the first item in a list.

Comment: @E4z9 Yeah but in C++ it guarantees that `operator =` is called. And it guarantees what happens if you don't define an `operator =`

Comment: @immibis in C `x=5;` doesn't guarentee that x will equal 5 in a multithreaded program ;)

Comment: @niceman Sure it does. It doesn't guarantee that you won't set x to something else before the next statement executes, however.

Comment: @immibis no it doesn't, you could have torn writes

Comment: @PasserBy Well then you just need to update the guarantee. `x=5;` guarantees that `x` will equal 5 if there is no way that `x` could be simultaneously modified in another thread or if `x` is a type that can be atomically written or if you're on a weak consistency model. That doesn't invalidate the point that there are guarantees. (Alternatively, you could state that *you* are guaranteeing to the compiler that you won't modify `x` in multiple threads, and if you break your guarantee the compiler is free to break its).

Comment: @immibis That's a great guarantee :)

Comment: @PasserBy Better than Haskell's "this expression will always evaluate to an integer unless it's `undefined` or it uses `unsafe` functions or calls foreign code that breaks this or that rule"?

Comment: @immibis I actually meant that not sarcastically. I don't actually know enough of Haskell to comment on how great Haskell's guarantees are, which is why I'm here

Comment: Haskell cannot be a good general purpose language for rapid application development. Each of Python,JavaScript,Go, C#, Java,and Swift are useful primarily for more specific purposes in addition to general development. If Haskell  is good for "rapid application development", that means it's good for nothing in particular.

Comment: @weberc2 and npm has more (and more not well perfected and not well maintained) JavaScript libraries than Go’s ecosystem. Quantity != quality.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII Why are you comparing libraries with shipped software products?

Comment: @weberc2 I reiterate that quantity != quality. Go still sucks regardless because for example it uses reflection instead of supporting true polymorphism. And thus for example GopherJS can’t do proper dead-code elimination. I also think Haskell is [not the right way](https://github.com/keean/zenscript/issues/35#issuecomment-416021733) to go though. Yet Go has far too many warts and deficiencies to used as a counter example to Haskell. Just as we wouldn’t compare s/w shipped for the crap-language JS as a counter-example to Haskell’s relevance.

Comment: @weberc2 I was just making the point that Go fanboys have a language more the league of crap languages like JavaScript and to not throw stones in their glass house. Goroutines and a C-like language with GC is not totally uninteresting but the lack of polymorphism really bites.

Comment: @weberc2 You appear to not know much about what I prefer. Scala and Kotlin don’t solve real problems? Kotlin is now the officially endorsed by Google language for Android apps— not Go. And we’re [designing to improve on them](https://github.com/keean/zenscript/issues/32#issuecomment-417161479). Go has one main thing going for it (other than being a better C with GC), i.e. goroutines, but we’ll [put that in a modern language](https://github.com/keean/zenscript/issues/17#issuecomment-416825734). But much of (not all of) the rest of the language is archaic. Go fanboys are fun to toy with.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII I guess I don't know your preferences, I'm trying to tease coherent points out of your posts, but I'll admit I'm not having much luck. Kotlin is endorsed because Android APIs are written in Java and Kotlin targets the Java virtual machine, not because functional programming languages are inherently better at shipping software rapidly, contra the original claim. :)

Comment: @weberc2 You have conflated FP and generics (aka type polymorphism). Go mostly lacks the latter, as it has some FP capability. Perhaps you were thinking _pure_ FP, but that wasn’t my complaint against Go. Go lacks even basic abstraction which requires generics. Perhaps [this discussion](https://github.com/keean/zenscript/issues/35#issuecomment-417672360) will help clarify.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIIII I don't believe I've mentioned either generics or pure FP, so I don't know why you think I've conflated them. Perhaps you read another comment and mistakenly attributed it to me? In any case, I'm quite familiar with generics and FP (pure and impure) so this seems like it's probably a misunderstanding. I do agree with you that Go does not have (user-defined) generics, however. Enjoy your long weekend!

Comment: "rapid" totally is not about Haskell. Modeling/prototyping in Haskell is usually slower than in Python/Go/Ruby about 10-20 times - experience of many Haskell/Go/Python dev groups working in parallel. Haskell is incredible complex and weird in places where everything must be clean and simple - it finds rocket science where everything is simple and direct: `myStruct.myField` in Haskell involves several extensions, concept of lenses and innovations in the language itself ;)

Answer (score 260):

I think people in this post are missing the most important point for anyone who has never used a functional programming language:  expanding your mind.  If you are new to functional programming then Haskell will make you think in ways you've never thought before.  As a result your programming in other areas and other languages will improve.  How much?  Hard to quantify.

Comment: I'm using an iPhone, Mac. Where is Haskell used? I mean for the apps I used they are written in Objective-C or Swift + something for database and servers. Swift can also be functional. So again I'm confused as to where it's used

Comment: Facebook does SPAM detection with it: https://code.facebook.com/posts/745068642270222/fighting-spam-with-haskell/

Comment: This answer, written in a different tone, says that Haskell is a great exercise for a programmer, which IMO doesn't make a great general purpose language

Comment: At Keera Studios we write iOS and Android games and apps using Haskell.

Comment: I totally agree with this.  I've written a lot of code over decades in imperative languages.  I've been exploring Haskell for a couple of months and it's opened my mind to things I hadn't thought about before.

Comment: @IvanPerez does it have multiplatform support like Kotlin?

Answer (score 95):

There is one good answer for what a general purpose language like Haskell is good for: writing programs in general.

For what it is used for in practice, I've three approaches to establishing that:

- [A tag cloud of Haskell library and app areas](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/what-is-haskell-good-for/), weighted by frequency on Hackage.

Indicates that it is good for graphics, networking, systems programming, data structures, databases, development,  text processing ...

- [Areas it is used in industry](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_industry) - a lot of DSLs, web apps, compiler design, networking, analysis, systems programming , ...

And finally, my opinion on what it is really strong at:

- [Problems where correctness matters, domain specific languages, and parallel and concurrent programming](http://web.archive.org/web/20130203023724/http://www.sdtimes.com/blog/post/2009/07/27/Everyonee28099s-talking-about-Haskell.aspx)

I hope that gives you a sense on how broad your question is, if it is to be answered with any specificity.

Comment: Tag cloud is broken

Comment: was the tag cloud generated using [wordcloud](https://github.com/chrisdone/wordcloud)?

Answer (score 36):

One example of Haskell in action is [xmonad](http://xmonad.org), a "featureful window manager in less than 1200 lines of code".

Answer (score 22):

From [the Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_industry):

> Haskell has a diverse range of use
>   commercially, from aerospace and
>   defense, to finance, to web startups,
>   hardware design firms and lawnmower
>   manufacturers. This page collects
>   resources on the industrial use of
>   Haskell.

According to Wikipedia, the [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) language was created out of the need to consolidate existing functional languages into a common one which could be used for future research in functional-language design.

It is apparent based on the information available that it has outgrown it's original purpose and is used for much more than research.  It is now considered a general purpose functional programming language.

If you're still asking yourself, "Why should I use it?", then read the [*Why use it?*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Why_use_Haskell.3F) section of the Haskell Wiki Introduction.

Answer (score 17):

Haskell is a general purpose programming language. It can be used for anything you use any other language to do. You aren't limited by anything but your own imagination. As for what it's suited for? Well, pretty much everything. There are few tasks in which a functional language does not excel.

And yes, I'm the Rayne from Dreamincode. :)

I would also like to mention that, in case you haven't read the Wikipedia page, functional programming is a paradigm like Object Oriented programming is a paradigm. Just in case you didn't know. Haskell is also functional in the sense that it works; it works quite well at that.

Just because a language isn't an Object Oriented language doesn't mean the language is limited by anything. Haskell is a general-purpose programming language, and is just as general purpose as Java.

Answer (score 11):

I have a cool one, facebook created a automated tool for rewriting PHP code. They parse the source into an abstract syntax tree, do some transformations:

```
if ($f == false) -> if (false == $f)
```

I don't know why, but that seems to be their particular style and then they pretty print it.

https://github.com/facebook/lex-pass

We use haskell for making small domain specific languages. Huge amounts of data processing. Web development. Web spiders. Testing applications. Writing system administration scripts. Backend scripts, which communicate with other parties.  Monitoring scripts (we have a DSL which works nicely together with munin, makes it much easier to write correct monitor code for your applications.)

All kind of stuff actually. It is just a everyday general purpose language with some very powerful and useful features, if you are somewhat mathematically inclined.

Comment: Re: the FB style, putting the false before the == means if you forget and only write a single = then the resulting behavior will be more obviously wrong instead of silently performing an unintended assignment operation and continuing normally

Comment: A that's clever, your force that particularly error to be known compile time then.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks, PHP has no compile time. This forces the exception to be raised where the mistake was, rather than leading to bizarre behavior or errors in distant code.

Comment: Although I see the benefit of writing `false` on the left, I don't see the point of using a tool to do it automatically: if you've already got a `==` operator then you already know you don't have the bug which that part of lex-pass is meant to catch, and if you've got a `=` instead there's no sure way to tell whether or not it's like that deliberately.

Comment: @JeremyList Maybe they are really stringent on the coding style. I can see that neatly formatted code invites to write more neatly formatted code. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @dfeuer But it has a phase where it builds up a symbol table? Maybe they catch it there then? Nevermind, this is off topic babble. I probably better check the source code myself.

Comment: I am a newbie to Haskell but find it relatively simple to explore machine learning codes with Haskell (such as kNN classifier and perceptron)

Answer (score 8):

From [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29):

> Haskell is a ***standardized, general-purpose purely functional
>   programming language***, with
>   non-strict semantics and strong static
>   typing. It is named after logician
>   Haskell Curry.

Basically Haskell can be used to create pretty much anything you would normally create using other general-purpose languages (e.g. C#, Java, C, C++, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

For example, for developing interactive, realtime HTML5 web applications. See [Elm](http://elm-lang.org), the compiler of which is implemented in Haskell and the syntax of which borrows a lot from Haskell's.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty good source for info about Haskell and its uses:

[**Open Source Haskell Releases and Growth**](http://archhaskell.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/open-source-haskell-releases-and-growth)

Comment: Link-only answers are not ideal. That said, since this question is closed it might be better to edit than to delete.

Comment: Seems this resource hasn't been updated since 2009.